# A set of vectors that is linearly dependent but each one of its subsets made of 2 vectors is linearly independent?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

Does linear space $\Bbb R^3$ contain a set of vectors that is linearly dependent but each one of its subsets made of $2$ vectors is linearly independent?

Answer: no. If a set of vectors is linearly dependent it means that at least one of its subsets made of $2$ vectors is linearly dependent.

Am I right?

Comment: No.  What if you have $3$ vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$ that lie in the same plane?

Comment: Then it doesn't work that "each one of it's subsets made of 2 vectors is linearly independent". As I have written in my supposed answer: "If a set of vectors is linearly dependent it means that at least one of it's subsets made of 2 vectors is linearly dependent."

Comment: Take the vectors $(0,1,0),(1,0,0),(1,1,0)$  as an example.  This shows that what you have written is false.

Comment: You are right, thank you!